# How do I return to the class after I've called my run method in my new GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

```
public LogInDatabase() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    picture = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    userNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    labelUserName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    passwordTextView = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    submitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Names = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    picture.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Learn/Image/newpackage/colors.jpg"))); // NOI18N

    labelUserName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    labelUserName.setText("User Name");
    labelUserName.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    labelPassword.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Georgia", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    labelPassword.setText("Password");
    labelPassword.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    submitButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    submitButton.setLabel("Submit");
    submitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            submitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Print");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Names.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    Names.setText("Team 1 Database - Dean Bailey, Josh Dixie, Ben Boudra, Trevor, Abel Amadou, Jalen");
    Names.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

    jLabel2.setText("Status");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(394, 394, 394)
            .addComponent(submitButton)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(passwordTextView, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(labelPassword))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(260, 260, 260)
                    .addComponent(userNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(labelUserName)))
            .addGap(325, 325, 325))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addComponent(picture, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                    .addComponent(Names, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 776, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(407, 407, 407)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {labelPassword, labelUserName, passwordTextView, userNameTextField});

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(Names, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(picture, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 322, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(labelUserName)
                .addComponent(userNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(labelPassword)
                .addComponent(passwordTextView, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(submitButton)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {labelPassword, labelUserName, passwordTextView, userNameTextField});

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    //If something returns a number then its inval
    userName = userNameTextField.getText();
    password = passwordTextView.getText();

    //call = new GetThePwUserTest(userName, password);


}                                            

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println(getPassword());
    System.out.println(getUserName());

    userPwHolder[0] = userName;
    userPwHolder[1] = password;

}                                        

public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
/* public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Set the Nimbus look and feel 
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    // If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
    // For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    // Create and display the form 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LogInDatabase().setVisible(true);
        }
    });       

}*/


public void run(){
            // Set the Nimbus look and feel 
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    // If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     //For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogInDatabase.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    // Create and display the form 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LogInDatabase().setVisible(true);
        }
    });       

  }

}
```

So I called run from another class. My main goal is to return to the class I called it from with the submit button that I have created. Can someone help me return to the class thats called it through the submit button?

Comment: Ahh, use a dialog...[How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: so if you close the dialog on clicking submit you don't return?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

A modal dialog will block at the code execution at the point the dialog is made visible and will return once the window has dismissed.  You would then be in a position to get what ever values you needed from the object (that it proivde access for you to get).

Alternatively, you could use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and simply call the class back when something has changed that it would need to know about.